# Problems plotting a variogram

Tags: r, geostatistics

I'm trying to plot a variogram of a Spatial data frame I got but the axis in the plotted image are wrong, they don't allow all points to be plotted. The R-studio version I'm using is 1.3 in Ubuntu 20.

Here is the code:

```
library(sp)
library(gstat)
library(readxl)

exceldata=read_excel('my_path')

dfdata=data.frame(exceldata)  #data frame
xy=dfdata[1:2]      #coords. of dfdata
values=dfdata[3]   #values of dfdata
Spatial_data=SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords=xy, data=values)  #spatial df

Spatial_data$logAu=log10(Spatial_data$au)

ve=variogram(logAu~1, 
             Spatial_data,   
             cutoff=10000,  
             width=50)
plot(ve)
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PArON.png) is an extract of the data frame (of a total of 150 elements).

However, the plot is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srh96.png). I'm learning R and I don't know what do the "cutoff" and "width" mean. How can I get the entire plot without those cuts in the distance axis?

Besides, the dput command shows this info: [img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwAgI.png) [img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYCNL.png) [img3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNRli.png)

Comment: Can you use `dput` to give us a sample of your data?

Comment: @the_one_neuron, I've already added the dput output